# how to divide nested array using RDD in spark

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to divide a nested array using RDD in Spark. For example, there is a `TextFile` that contains four sentences, like this:

> "he is good", "she is good", "I am good", "we are good"

I used `val arr = sc.textFile("filename").map(_.split(" "))` command and got this:

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(he, is, good), 
                             Array(she, is, good), 
                             ... )
```

I want to use each array elements (i.e. `Array(he, is, good)`) but I don't know how to divide this. How can I divide this?

Comment: I think you would get an `RDD[Array[String]]` (from a text file with the lines of elements you enumerated), not an `Array[Array[String]]`. I am not sure how you would like to "divide", you can `map` the results and the argument will be what you have described.

Comment: As @GáborBakos says, it's important to be clear about what you mean when you say "divide". Can you provide us what your intended output looks like?

Comment: First, @GáborBakos you are right. The array is `RDD[Array[String]`. if I use array.collect in spark-shell, then `Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(he, is, good), ...)` Second, ` the "divide" means that I can get elements of 2d array. For example, there is a 2d array(Array[Array[String]) like above, and if I use Java language, I can get its elements using `for` loop and `get` method. But, I don't know how to use `for` loop in spark using RDD. The output that I want is each array in 2d array like `Array(he, is, good), Array(she, is, good), Array(I, am, good), Array(we, are ,good)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by 'divided', but typically in functional programming languages, when you want to do anything with each element of a collection (or 'iterable'), you can use the `map` function. `map` converts each element based on a function you passed it. For example, in a worksheet you can do this:

```
val sentences = Array(Array("he", "is", "good"),
                      Array("she", "is", "very", "good"))

def yodaize(sentence: Array[String]): Array[String] =  {
  val reversed = sentence.reverse
  println("Yoda says, '%s'".format(reversed.mkString(" ")))
  reversed
}

yodaize(Array("I", "am", "small"))

val yodaSentences = sentences.map(yodaize)
```

The function `yodaize` does two things: it reverses the sentence passed to it and *as a side effect* prints out the reversed sentence. The worksheet output of the above is:

```
sentences: Array[Array[String]] = [[Ljava.lang.String;@faffecf

yodaize: yodaize[](val sentence: Array[String]) => Array[String]

Yoda says, 'small am I'
res0: Array[String] = [Ljava.lang.String;@4bf1c779

Yoda says, 'good is he'
Yoda says, 'good very is she'
yodaSentences: Array[Array[String]] = [[Ljava.lang.String;@40a19a85
```

It's hard to see directly here, but `yodaSentences` is the original array with each sub-array reversed:

```
Array(Array("good", "is", "he"),
      Array("good", "very", "is", "she"))
```

With `map` you can pass in any function. It can directly convert the element or have a side effect. In this manner functional languages can deal with each element without really ever needing to 'divide' them. Note that other functions like `flatMap`, `foldLeft` and `filter` can be used to perform other sorts of permutations on your collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it's not what I am looking for.  The "divide" means that I can get elements of 2d array. For example, there is a 2d array(Array[Array[String]) like above, and if I use Java language, I can get its elements using for loop and get method. But, I don't know how to use for loop in spark using RDD. The output that I want is each array in 2d array like Array(he, is, good), Array(she, is, good), Array(I, am, good), Array(we, are ,good).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `foreach` both for `Array`s and `RDD`s:

```
yourReference.map(arrayOfStrings => arrayOfStrings.mkString)
```

or

```
yourReference.foreach(arrayOfStrings => println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfStrings)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use `foreach` for `Array` as you say. And it worked! Thank you~ have a nice day~